# AWS Secrets Manager with Database inside RDS (Postgres) - How to store password for a database inside RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

I have one RDS postgres instance which hosts multiple databases, these databases have their own usernames/passwords with which different applications connect. I want to store passwords for different databases in secrets manager but in secret manager i only see option to select the RDS instance and not the DBs inside that, so is it possible to store passwords for different databases in one RDS instance using secret type as "Credentials for RDS database", if yes then how ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can.** What you see in AWS Console, is just a simplified convenience frontend for storing master root password for your RDS. But in SM you can store **any string** you want, including for credentials for multiple databases hosted on a single RDS instance.

Just choose:

```
Select secret type -> Other type of secrets
```

and specify json string, or any format you want in `Plaintext`.

Comment: That i can do but i will have to rotate those credentials manually using lambda etc.., that's why i am looking for if it is natively supported by secrets manager using secret type "Credentials for RDS database".

Comment: @user10916892 For that you would have to use AWS CLI probably, not console. You can specify dbname using [templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_available-rotation-templates.html#sar-template-mysql-singleuser). Obviously, each database needs its own secret.